# load images from web in UIImageView inside UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

How do I go about loading images from my website into UITableView?  What is the best way for performance?  And how would one handle rerendering the images as the table cells get reused?

And how can I pass the image from the tableView to the cell during didSelect..Row method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for performance is to do lazy loading. You Shouldn't download an image the user is not viewing. A sample code is available at he below link

[Lazy TableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

It may look a bit complicated at first, but actually it is not. If you are not sure how to modify your tableview for this code, modify this codes's rootview controller for your need.
Eg: Load a custom cell from nib

PS: You have to pass the image link in xml to use this code

Answer (score 0):

Take the number of pixels all the images will have together (ideally you can make small perfectly sized images on your web site?) and then multiply by 4. That's how many bytes you are dealing with. For your users sake, keep it low!

Download the images in NSOperations synchronously (although apple docs have much more complicated solutions), into an NSMutableDictionary, with key being the url, and the png or jpeg data (or the actual UIImage) as the value. You need to use @synchronize() around all access to the cached dictionary, as you will be accessing the array from several threads.

When you get a memory warning, just tell the dictionary to remove all items. (inside a sync block)

```
-(void)somememorywarning;
{
    @synchronized(gImageCacheDict)
    {
        [gImageCacheDict removeAllObjects];
    }
 }
```

I leave the table cell stuff to the docs, etc but you don't do it the didSelect call..

Comment: You start downloading as soon as a tableview cell needs the image, and use a placeholder until the real thing arrives. Everytime an image is downloaded successfully, you can post a notification on the main thread to tell your table view to reloadData.

Comment: How do I download the images?  Would a WebView be better?  I don't even know where to begin on downloading the image?  Thanks for the advice so far.

Comment: You can use   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
  [NSURL URLWithString:@" h ttp;//yoursite.png"]];

Comment: This will take you a while to learn, I think. Be patient. Take small steps. Spend an hour finding sample code that is as close to your table as you can find. You can create a UIImage with [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];